# How can you prevent Google from saying "if you just said something..."

Tags: voice-command, google-voice-actions

If I start a voice search but change my mind and cancel it, sometimes it will say " if you just said something I didn't hear what it was".

Is there any way to disable this?

Comment: Are you rooted ?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I forgot to mention it.

Comment: Xposed module App settings..give it a shot and see if you can mute...too busy for me to check

Comment: and if you're not rooted? I don't want things to activate on their own or if i accidentally knock against something